# How to pick one from multiply widgets for home screen using 3d touch?

Tags: ios, today-extension, ios-extensions

When I was using only one today widget it was very simple and was like this:

[image]

Now I added a second today widget to my app, and it is like this:

[image]

Why it disappeared? What is wrong? Shouldnt be there two today widgets? Can I decide what widget should be preferred here?

Apple says:

> **Choose a widget for the quick action list**. If your app has multiple widgets, pick one to appear in the quick action menu that appears when someone applies pressure to your app icon on the Home screen using 3D Touch.

But where to do this? Is it user or developer site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set **bundle identifier** of preferred widget to `UIApplicationShortcutWidget` key in info.plist of your app target.

[image]

Comment: So there is no possibility to let the user choose which widget he prefers?