# How to show the correct GUI on a QStackedWidget depending on the choice on a QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstackedwidget

How to properly show the right user interface on the `QStacked Widget` depending on the choice on `QListWidget`?

Below I have a `QDialog` that contains:

`1 QListWidget`

`1 QStackedWidget`

[image: stack]

Depending on the selected choice of the list, for example, Vessel Position System, or Output the interface should look like below, but **the problem is that** unfortunately the `QStacked Widget` is currently not changing the `QWidgets` as I select `QListWidgets`, actually is not showing anything. [A Minimal Verifiable Example can be found here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/stackedwidget/src/master/). Just clone it and it will work:

[image: output]

Below the code:

**optionsdialog.h**

```
#include <QDialog>
#include "vesselpossystemwidget.h"
#include "outputdialog.h"
#include "sonarsystem.h"
namespace Ui {
class OptionsDialog;
}

class OptionsDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit OptionsDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~OptionsDialog();

private:
    Ui::OptionsDialog *ui;
    VesselPosSystemWidget *mVesPos;
    OutputDialog *mOutput;
    SonarSystem *mSonar;
};

#endif // OPTIONSDIALOG_H
```

**optionsdialog.h**

```
#include "optionsdialog.h"
#include "ui_optionsdialog.h"

OptionsDialog::OptionsDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::OptionsDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    switch(ui->stackedWidget->currentIndex()){

      case 0:
        // Go to positioning system
        mVesPos = new VesselPosSystemWidget();
        mVesPos->show();
        break;
      case 1:
        // Go to sonar set up...
        mSonar = new SonarSystem();
        mSonar->show();
        break;
      case 2:
        // Go to output
        mOutput = new OutputDialog();
        mOutput->show();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
}

OptionsDialog::~OptionsDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**vesselposwidget.h**

```
#include <QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class VesselPosSystemWidget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class VesselPosSystemWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    VesselPosSystemWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~VesselPosSystemWidget();

private:
    Ui::VesselPosSystemWidget *ui;
};
#endif // VESSELPOSSYSTEMWIDGET_H
```

**vesselposwidget.cpp**

```
#include "vesselpossystemwidget.h"
#include "ui_vesselpossystemwidget.h"

VesselPosSystemWidget::VesselPosSystemWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::VesselPosSystemWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

VesselPosSystemWidget::~VesselPosSystemWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**output.h**

```
#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class OutputDialog;
}

class OutputDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit OutputDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~OutputDialog();

private:
    Ui::OutputDialog *ui;
};

#endif // OUTPUTDIALOG_H
```

**output.cpp**

```
#include "outputdialog.h"
#include "ui_outputdialog.h"

OutputDialog::OutputDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::OutputDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

OutputDialog::~OutputDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

I am exploring the possibility to use a `QStacked Widget` as I am not very familiar with it and wanted to practice with a basic example. I was investigating [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40693701/how-to-pick-one-from-multiply-widgets-for-home-screen-using-3d-touch) and also [this one](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html)

Also from the [same](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) source there is more documentation that I read. However I was not fully able to understand clearly the use of this particular widget.

In addition to that I tried a `switch - case` loop as I shown above on the code but I Am not sure why it didn't work

Can anyone please provide some guidance on how to properly show the right user interface on the `QStacked Widget` depending on the choice on `QListWidget`? Any direction for solving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: _[A Minimal Verifiable Example can be found here.](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/stackedwidget/src/master/)_ is by far no [mcve]. In an MCVE, you would remove all the widgets which are neither `QStackedWidget` nor `QListWidget`. Stacking some simple `QLabel`s would be fully sufficient to illustrate whether the `QStackedWidget` shows the intended page.

Comment: Are you aware that you try to add a `QDialog` "OutputDialog" to `QStackedWidget`? I doubt that this is producing the expected result. You should make "OutputDialog" of another class e.g. `QWidget`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#details) is a container widget for multiple child widgets which shows only one of them at a time.

Hence, all child widgets should be added at once.

The `currentIndex` can be used to control which of them should be visible currently.

A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate this – `testQStackedWidgetMin.cc`:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWinMain;
  QHBoxLayout qHBox;
  QListWidget qList;
  qList.addItem(QString::fromUtf8("Config. 1"));
  qList.addItem(QString::fromUtf8("Config. 2"));
  qList.addItem(QString::fromUtf8("Output"));
  qHBox.addWidget(&qList);
  QStackedWidget qStack;
  QLabel qConfig1(QString::fromUtf8("<b>Config Page 1</b>"));
  qStack.addWidget(&qConfig1);
  QLabel qConfig2(QString::fromUtf8("<b>Config Page 2</b>"));
  qStack.addWidget(&qConfig2);
  QLabel qOutput(QString::fromUtf8("<b>Output Page</b>"));
  qStack.addWidget(&qOutput);
  qHBox.addWidget(&qStack, 1);
  qWinMain.setLayout(&qHBox);
  qWinMain.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qList, &QListWidget::currentRowChanged,
    &qStack, &QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex);
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: Snapshot of testQStackedWidgetMin]

**Note:**

One of the essential statements of this sample is the signal-slot connection:

```
  QObject::connect(&qList, &QListWidget::currentRowChanged,
    &qStack, &QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex);
```

The [QListWidget::currentRowChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#currentRowChanged) signal of the `QListWidget qList` is connected to the [QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) function of the `QStackedWidget qStack`.
This is responsible for updating of `qStack` for any (interactive) row change in `qList`.

---

A not so minimal sample according to the intention of OP – `testQStackedWidget.cc`:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

class Config1: public QWidget {
  private:
    // GUI
    QVBoxLayout _qVBox;
    QLabel _qLbl;

  public:
    // constructor.
    Config1();
    // destructor.
    virtual ~Config1() = default;
    // disabled:
    Config1(const Config1&) = delete;
    Config1& operator=(const Config1&) = delete;
};


Config1::Config1(): QWidget()
{
  // setup GUI
  _qLbl.setText(QString::fromUtf8("<b>Config Page 1</b>"));
  _qVBox.addWidget(&_qLbl);
  setLayout(&_qVBox);
}

class Config2: public QWidget {
  private:
    // GUI
    QVBoxLayout _qVBox;
    QLabel _qLbl;

  public:
    // constructor.
    Config2();
    // destructor.
    virtual ~Config2() = default;
    // disabled:
    Config2(const Config2&) = delete;
    Config2& operator=(const Config2&) = delete;
};

Config2::Config2(): QWidget()
{
  _qLbl.setText(QString::fromUtf8("<b>Config Page 2</b>"));
  _qVBox.addWidget(&_qLbl);
  setLayout(&_qVBox);
}

class Output: public QWidget {
  private:
    // GUI
    QVBoxLayout _qVBox;
    QLabel _qLbl;

  public:
    // constructor.
    Output();
    // destructor.
    virtual ~Output() = default;
    // disabled:
    Output(const Output&) = delete;
    Output& operator=(const Output&) = delete;
};

Output::Output(): QWidget()
{
  _qLbl.setText(QString::fromUtf8("<b>Output Page</b>"));
  _qVBox.addWidget(&_qLbl);
  setLayout(&_qVBox);
}

class OptionDialog: public QDialog {
  private:
    // GUI
    QHBoxLayout _qHBox;
    QListWidget _qList;
    QStackedWidget _qStack;
    Config1 _qConfig1;
    Config2 _qConfig2;
    Output _qOutput;

  public:
    // constructor.
    OptionDialog();
    // destructor.
    virtual ~OptionDialog() = default;
    // disabled:
    OptionDialog(const OptionDialog&) = delete;
    OptionDialog& operator=(const OptionDialog&) = delete;
};

OptionDialog::OptionDialog(): QDialog()
{
  // setup GUI
  _qList.addItem(QString::fromUtf8("Config. 1"));
  _qList.addItem(QString::fromUtf8("Config. 2"));
  _qList.addItem(QString::fromUtf8("Output"));
  _qHBox.addWidget(&_qList);
  _qStack.addWidget(&_qConfig1);
  _qStack.addWidget(&_qConfig2);
  _qStack.addWidget(&_qOutput);
  _qHBox.addWidget(&_qStack, 1);
  setLayout(&_qHBox);
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&_qList, &QListWidget::currentRowChanged,
    &_qStack, &QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex);
}

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  OptionDialog qDlgOpt;
  qDlgOpt.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: Snapshot of testQStackedWidget]

---

The `CMakeLists.txt`, I used for creation of the VisualStudio solution:

```
project(QStackedWidget)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_executable(testQStackedWidgetMin
  testQStackedWidgetMin.cc)

target_link_libraries(testQStackedWidgetMin
  Qt5::Widgets)

add_executable(testQStackedWidget
  testQStackedWidget.cc)

target_link_libraries(testQStackedWidget
  Qt5::Widgets)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Scheff for your time and for taking the time to write this very detailed example. The different versions gave me a much better understanding of the use of the `QStackedWidget` and how the logic works for showing the correct interface! Very very much appreciated!! :)